How execute js code in rails 7 'create.turbo_stream.erb' file
here is my comment controller code
    def create
     @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
     @feed = Feed.find(params[:comment][:feed_id])
     @comment.commentable = @feed
     @parent = params[:comment][:parent] if params[:comment][:parent].present?
     respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.save
      format.turbo_stream
      format.html { redirect_to feeds_path, notice: "Comment was successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
     else
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
   end

my 'create.turbo_stream.erb' code is below
  <%if @parent.present?%>
     <%= turbo_stream.update("feeds-list-parent-#{@parent}",
          partial: "feeds/feed",
          locals: { feed: @feed }) %>
  <%else%>
      <%= turbo_stream.update("feeds-list-#{@feed.id}",
          partial: "feeds/feed",
          locals: { feed: @feed }) %>
  <%end%>
  console.log('hi') # this is not working here and no log. also <script> tag is not working.

How this is possible to execute some js code, beacause i want to hide pop up div using js here?
i tried different option to execute js but not working.

<script> tag has to be part of the turbo stream

but  not executing console.log inside script tag. anyother way to execute js code.

<script> tag has to be inside the turbo stream to be executable:
<%= turbo_stream.update "feeds-list-#{@feed.id}" do %>
  <%= render "feeds/feed", feed: @feed %>
  <script>
    console.log("hi")
  </script>
<% end %>

or in a separate turbo stream:
<%= turbo_stream.update "feeds-list-#{@feed.id}", partial: "feeds/feed", locals: {feed: @feed} %>

<%= turbo_stream.after "feeds-list-#{@feed.id}" do %>
  <script>
    console.log("hi")
  </script>
<% end %>


this approach dosn't work and log 'hi' into console. see https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/1247#issuecomment-2064408330

this is also working <%= turbo_stream.after "feeds-list-#{@feed.id}" do %>

<% end %>

I have used another approach to do it:
    <button type="submit" data-action="click->comment#closePopup" data-turbo="true" class="inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-200 dark:focus:ring-blue-900 hover:bg-blue-800">
    Comment
    </button>

